# Squeak after lid close

Tags: power-management

I have a strange problem with Ubuntu 10.10 - when I close the laptop lid (Samsung r580) it makes a very high squeak. This doesn't occur on Win7. I am currently using 2.6.35.27 kernel. If you need some more info to help me with this problem just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just as a clue for somebody else to answer this, to me this sounds like a problem with ALSA going into suspend. @Rey can you confirm that the laptop is going into suspend (aka sleep) when you close the lid?

Comment: Nope, it does not go to sleep when I close the lid, it makes only this high sound. But while looking for solution to my problem I found that some ppl had same problem as U.

Comment: I have "quite" the same kind of problem with 10.04 and my 1215n asus... Sometimes when I start ubuntu I get very squeaky sound during the startup drums and the system hangs up. Then I restart and it works perfectly. Also sleep kills my audio. Very frustrating.

Comment: This is really old and not answered. Because of that I think we should close as not reproducible. Anyone else with a similar problem should ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, now I can confirm that recent power-managment update fixed the problem.... finaly... after about 3 months I can close the lid without being annoyed by that sound :) Thx everyone for helping!

Comment: blahhhh... it has started again... plugging in headphonesmakes the problem go away when closing the lid but it's not a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it would be something like this: If the microphone feedback (input level) is set too high this can occur because of the **magnets** on the lid...

Not sure if it's the same problem as yours though, but seems to fit the description.

Answer (score 0):

See if there is a BIOS option to turn off signals related to power management.

Comment: The only thing related to power managment is keeping charge level at 80%.

Comment: This answer may help someone. It would be even better if it provided more information, but it's still [better as an answer than as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this isn't the beep from the suspend action? Suspend in another way, if it happens as well. That is your answer.

Could also be the soundcard giving a death rattle as you cruely cut off its power. Use headphones to silence the speakers before closing the lid, see if that shows you the cause.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it wasn't beep from suspend action (on lid close I have no action set) and the sound was very anoying. Funny thing that after yesterdays updates (propably power managment update) laptop does not squeak anymore after lid close. Maybe it's solve or maybe it must be triggered by something. I'll keep testing to see if it still happens.

Comment: plugging in headphones slienced the speaker... but it's not a solution unfortunetly :/