# Microphone output gets sent to speakers

Tags: 10.10, laptop, headphones

I have a strange problem with headphones - when I plug them in I can hear in them, apart from normal sounds like music, everything microphone collects. And by everything I mean everything.... i hear every tap on the touchpad... I hear how HDD works. It is pretty anoying. My laptop is Samsung R580, I'm using 10.10 with 2.6.36-28 kernel. If U need any more info just ask. Thx for any help!

P.S. this may be connected with another unresolved problem I have: [Squeak after lid close](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28452/squeak-after-lid-close)

P.P.S. sometimes without without headphones when I tap the microphone I hear the "tap" in the speakers

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the microphone in the Profile for your sound device. This can be done by entering the sound preferences and in the "Hardware" Tab, choose the profile that better adjusts to your sound device.

[image]

In this example my screenshot is showing several profiles but my Internal Audio device only supports those "Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input".

In the same example as my device shown in the screenshot, if I choose the Analog Surround 4.0 Output with no Analog Stereo Input, I get the Microphone silent.

Give a try and let's see what happens.

You can change your preferences each time when you need the microphone turned on for video-conferencing, voice recording or something else.

Good luck!

Comment: Because my problem does not occur everytime I plug my headphones I'll have test this solution for a while. I'll keep U posted on the results. I had stereo duplex set, now I have switched to 4.0 + analog stereo input.

Comment: Setting your profile to Analog Stereo Duplex or Analog Stereo Output will disable the microphone's input, which may solve your issue. If you need to use a different profile, try changing the microphone's input levels to the lowest in order to reduce the feedback from your device which may also be a good solution. What I see is that -somehow- your device is "always-open" to the mic's input and -depending on your sound device- this can be auto-enabled by the driver at the boot when the headphones are plugged in. Have you checked out how the device behaves when headphones plugged or unplugged?

Comment: I had Analog Stereo Duplex and this problem occured even with microphone set to mute. Yesterday I started testing settings with 4.0 + analog stereo input. It may take me a while cause the problem  is not persistent. I had plugged headphones few times and used them for a while on new settings and so far no problems.

Comment: Ok now I can say that non of the settings in audio preferences works... even when I disable sound I still can hear the tap on the microphone in my speakers... and now I see that is directly connected with my other problem with closing the lid (link in first post)

Comment: It's sad to hear that but I have also experienced this in the past. I am not sure why this happen, it seems that there is a different microphone installed which isn't in control of the sound device itself. May I ask you about your laptop's microphones placement? I have seen this behavior in those laptops which features two small holes in the top of the lid (one in the left and one in the right). If this is the case, then may be we are talking about a stereo microphone. In which case, this may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/31572/skype-doesnt-find-my-audio-input/31663#31663

Comment: I have mono microphone - single hole near left ctrl. I tried plugging headphones as an external microphone but it didn't change anything. Also pavucontrol didn't help :/

Comment: After some time I can say that with 4.0 + analog stereo input this problem occurs very rarely :) THX for help