# Skype doesn't find my audio input

Tags: 10.04

Skype doesn't find my audio input. If I click on the "Microphone" no other suggestions appears, my web camera works.

In windows everything works.

[image: Skype sound options]

This is my audio preferences.
[image]

audio settings.

[image]

Comment: I had the **exact** same settings on Ubuntu 10.10 (Although that's now been updated to 11.04 :P). I have a feeling that the answer will work for me as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I've found to make my internal mic work in my laptops is to use `pavucontrol` (install it from the homonymous package) and disabling the volume of a channel (the right or the left one), since most of microphones are mono in fact.

This is an huge workaround, by the way. I guess that this annoying bug should be fixed somewhere!

[image: Pavucontrol - Input volume settings]

Comment: Why should I disable one mic? I don't get it what should I expect? What is your point?

Comment: I know I didn't ask this question, but upvoted. Worked for me. FINALLY I HAVE SKYPE WORKING. :D

Comment: @Alvar I'm not disabling a mic, but disabling a channel. Many internal mics are considered as stereo by PulseAudio (or alsa?) while they are really monoo. Using both channels causes the microphone not to work at all!

Comment: WOW! This is amazing! but it should be installed form the begging or it should be done in a better way...
It's not that big of a workaround just install it and disable a mic simple! :)

Comment: I have a problem, this answer doesn't work for me now! In this newer version I have to adjust both channels, I can't just mute one. please help!!!! :(

Answer (score 6):

Under Sound Preferences, please post the "Hardware Tab" in order to check your profile, which should use at least an output + an input being in use. Otherwise, your hardware is not using the input profile which can be chosen right there.

This answer may be changed after your posting in order to give you further details. Here is a sample. Thank you.

[image]

### Edit

Here is the [conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/skype-fixing) in the general chat room.

Comment: Sorry none of them works, I don't have as many as you do, but still none of them works.

Comment: If you are in a Laptop, the Internal Audio Analog Stereo may refer to a device which is not connected to your sound device. This is the case with the Compaq Presario V3000 (V3616LA) and some netbooks (Acer, eMachines, Benq, etc.), try connecting a microphone into the Mic Jack (external connector) and check what happen. This may solve your issue as the device is named but not being used by any physical device.

Comment: I doesn't have an external microphone to plug in sorry. new screenshot uploaded.

Comment: Choose the "Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input" and check it again.

Comment: join the chat man! Allan has helpt a lot..

Comment: The conversation in the chat room is placed in the Edit for this answer for the convenience of the rest of the people. Can be edited and removed by anybody if needed. Thank you!

Comment: that edit is amazing! good job! :D

Comment: I've created a chat bookmark of the conversation to keep the answer clean.

Comment: Thank you @Octavian Damiean! Someday teach me how to do these tricks. :)

Comment: I'd be glad to, just join the chat and I'll tell you. ;)

Answer (score -2):

Make sure to use the latest Skype beta version for Linux from http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/. Older versions do not work properly with Pulse Audio. Also uncheck the "Allow skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels", it caused a lot of trouble for me. After that, reset all your mixer levels by opening a command-line and running `alsactl init`.

Comment: Error: A later version is already installed
and that was the latest version on their site.

Comment: The ubuntu repository has made some localized changes to the skype package, thats why you're seeing that. Linux skype is in sorry shape and needs some serious revisions.