# How do I change the channels in pavelcontrol?

Tags: 11.04, sound, skype

I had [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/31572/10698) problem in 10.04 and it was solved.

`pavucontrol` was the solution the last time, I muted one channel and the microphone worked then. But now in Ubuntu 11.04 I have to change both channels at the same time. as the screenshot shows.

[image]

So here is my problem.

I can't use my built in microphone in skype, but in windows I can.

`skype -version` gave: Skype 2.2.0.35

Comment: Have you gone into Skype's Options > Audio Devices and unchecked "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels"? I get the problem of Skype just muting my mic whenever this is not unchecked. Also, make sure for Input Devices in your Sound Preferences that the proper mic is selected and at the correct volume.

Comment: no I don't have the problem that it gets muted I have the problem that it doesn't record any sound, the setting is set to max!

Comment: there is only one mic available and that is pulseaudio. I have been able to use my AKG k630 headphones as a mic if I plug them into the sound input, but the sound has a lot of base noice and it's hard to hear what is say, so that wont work.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant. Are you able to record sounds through another program (e.g. Sound Recorder)? Just checking if the problem is Skype-specific, or something else.

Comment: no, It's working perfectly in windows btw! ( :( ) But last time in 10.04 I was able to mute one channel, and then it worked as it should, I just guess that I need to do that again, but how?! (I'm forced to control both.) is there a way to mute one channel?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with `pavucontrol` and I'm running out of ideas, but I'm going to take a guess from your provided screenshot...I see a button with a lock icon on it next to your ALSA plug-in setting. Can you try clicking that and see if the channels can be moved separately?

Comment: That was genious! make an answer and I will provide a screenshot! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `pavucontrol`, click the lock button next to the "**ALSA plug-in [java]**: ALSA Playback" section. This will unlock the two channels from each other and let them move independently again, then the issue can be solved by muting one channel as usual.

[image]